# Is that possible to communicate JMS Topic of HornetQ with ActiveMQ or vice versa

Tags: activemq-artemis, jboss6.x, hornetq, wildfly-18

I have a HornetQ project on JBoss 6 using JDK-6, and an ActiveMQ project on WildFly 18 using JDK-11. Can I access the HornetQ topic in the ActiveMQ project or vice versa?

Comment: Are you talking about the ActiveMQ version embedded in WildFly 18 (a.k.a. ActiveMQ Artemis)?

Answer (score 0):

If you're using ActiveMQ Artemis embedded in WildFly 18 then you should be able to connect to it from your HornetQ client because ActiveMQ Artemis is based on the HornetQ code-base and has maintained backwards compatibility with older HornetQ clients.

However, you will not be able to use the ActiveMQ Artemis JMS client to talk to HornetQ.